# How do I get the URL of an image inside a module directory?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

In the directory containing a custom module, I have a directory containing images.

How do I get the URL of those images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
drupal_get_path('module', $module_name);
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way, like referred above, is to use the relative path to site root:

```
'/' . drupal_get_path('module', $module_name) . '/img1.jpg'
```

Using it without the trailing slash in the beginning would break it on multiple level aliases, e.g. http://www.your_site.dev/category/2012/11/02/

Comment: Thanks! `drupal_get_path()` without a preceding slash was messing me up.

Answer (score 1):

A more complete example that works in Drupal 7 and 8. All other answers just show how to return the path to the module but not how to actually make a URL out of it.

```php
<?php
$module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule');
$image_path = "$module_path/images/img1.jpg";
$image_url = file_create_url($image_path);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// path
drupal_get_path('module', $module_name) . '/images';
```

<del>file_create_url( drupal_get_path('module', $module_name) ) . '/images';</del>

Comment: Incorrect. The `file_create_url` will always work in relation to _default/files_ not the module directory so the URLs would end up like http://www.your_site.dev/sites/default/files/sites/all/modules/your_module/images which is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, correct. `file_code_url` will return the URL under /sites/default/files. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get proper URL of your image you need to append `base_path()` at the beginning of your image path. The correct URL would be:

`$url = base_path() . drupal_get_path("module", "MY_MODULE") . "/image.png";`